# How to go about resurrecting an old question that already has an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Quite a while ago I asked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24565/add-additional-text-to-grouped-bibliography-entries-with-biblatex) question about `biblatex` receiving a "hackish" answer that solved my problem at the time (although it is certainly not perfect as I have to change the content of my .bib files) but in the comments I was informed that an upcoming version of `biblatex` would provide a more canonical solution to my problem. Now, I tried finding out how to do it right, but my knowledge of `biblatex` is not good enough to find what I am searching for. Should I ask this question again in a revised form (e.g. I would like to request a language sensitive solution to my problem that doesn't tinker with the .bib files) or should I edit my original question and award a bounty to get enough attention? I know the question of resurrecting questions vs. asking them again has been raised before but there is an aspect I couldn't find: If I go with resurrection, what should I do with the accepted answer? Should I unaccept it? Wouldn't that be kind of "rude" as it was the only possible solution at the time and did solve the question I asked.

Comment: **Option 1**: Add an edit(Looking for Canonical answer with Updated version biblatex) and comment/inform to @person-who-answered if he can update the answer with new biblatex. **Option 2**: Add a bounty(Looking for Canonical answer with Updated version biblatex) **Option 3**:[Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117). **To me**: Option 1 Looks the best with least effort and rep  lost. but wait for others call also

Comment: @texenthusiast Thanks, a notification of the person who answered the original question might indeed provide a respectful way of unaccepting his answer. Haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm the one who provided the "hackish" answer and I think unaccepting it plus updating the original question ("I'm looking for a canonical answer") is the correct way in this case. Adding a bounty would ensure additional notice, but is *not* required.

Comment: Ok, then I will do it this way (and would happily accept an updated answer you might provide :)). I hope the word "hackish" was ok to use (I liked your answer at the time, it did the trick - so I meant no disrespect) - I'm not a native speaker and couldn't think of a better word.

Comment: @Philipp You should rather expect an answer by Audrey or PLK, as I'm not familiar with the "related entry" feature. BTW, I think "hackish" was a quite appropriate wording -- but then, I'm as much a native speaker as you.

Comment: I've never awarded a bounty before. What would be the appropriate kind of bounty to choose: "Canonical answer required" or "Current answer(s) are outdated"?

Comment: @Philipp If (and only if) the old answer still works, I'd choose "Canonical answer required".

Comment: Thanks, it does still compile all right, so "Canonical answer required" it is then.